# javascript confirm (cancel) still submits form when returning false

Tags: javascript

When I submit and click OK it continues but when I press "cancel" it submits anyway.   I tried using this code but the submit and cancel button still do the same thing.

```
model.saveForm = function() {
    var r = confirm("Press a button");
    alert(p);
    if (r == true) {
        x = "You pressed OK!";

        if (!validateRequiredNew()) return;
        model.saving(true);

        // check if group id is needed
        var generatedGroupIdPromise = null;
        // if (model.selectedUsers().length > 1 || model.selectedUsers()[0].selectedRoles().length > 1) {
        generatedGroupIdPromise = $.ajax({
            url: '../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/GroupIdGeneratorList',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{Title: 'dummy'}",
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json"
        });                         

    } else if (r == false){
        x = "You pressed Cancel!"; 
    }
```

And the aspx page:

```
<button data-bind="click: saveForm, visible: !saving()">Submit Request</button>
```

Comment: Is the `<button>` within a `<form>`, and it's the `<form>` that's still submitting?  Note that by default, a `<button>` is `type="submit"` - if you've got it inside a `<form>` you may want to make it `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but you __never__ need `== true` in JS's `if`. Just use: `if (r) {` and replace `} else if (r == false){` with `} else {`

Comment: are you sure that r is false?
can you show the confirm function?

Comment: Hi Cerbrus, yes it was that originally but I changed it when I was trying to find a solution. James the submit button is sitting just after the forms closing tag.

Comment: @JosephKhella [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) _"`result` is a boolean value"_

Comment: Hello joseph. I did an alert(r) and got a return of false when I clicked cancel it returned false

Comment: try to put `return false;` into `model.saveForm` method

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev that worked. If you like you can put that as an answer and I'll tick it and upvote it

Comment: OK, @KieranHanna. i answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `return false;` or `event.preventDefault();` into your method.